# How to draw a border around two cells in a IText table?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, itext

I use [IText](http://itextpdf.com/) to generate a PDF. So i use the following code to generate a table:

```
    iTextSharp.text.Table aTable = new iTextSharp.text.Table(10, 7);

   //Row 1
   aTable.AddCell(new Cell("ANDC"), 0, 4);
   aTable.AddCell(new Cell("0.123"), 0, 5);
```

Now i want to draw a border around these two cells. I know how to draw a border around the table or a single cell, but how can I do it around two cells?

it's important to note that there are also other cells in the table than the two metnionedin the code above.

Answer (score 1):

First, PdfPTable and PdfPCell give you much more control, use them instead.

Second, I recommend a cell event handler.  You'll need to keep track of which cell is which, so you can draw the appropriate line art at (only) the appropriate time/place.

Ah, since cell event handlers are cell specific, you can whip up a different one for the left and right cells, or just a handler for the second one that draws at double its own width... or the first one could record its width and the second could draw both with that info, or...

You get the idea.

```
PdfPCell leftCell = new PdfPCell();
...
leftCell.setCellEvent(new MyLeftCellEvent());
myPdfPTable.addCell(leftCell);

PdfPCell rightCell = new PdfPCell();
...
rightCell.setCellEvent(new MyRightCellEvent());
myPdfPTable.addCell(rightCell);
```

---

#### The Other Way

You can switch off specific borders in a PdfPCell (which derive from rectangle):

```
cell.disableSide(Rectangle.RIGHT);
otherCell.disableSide(Rectangle.LEFT);
```

MUCH less code.